# ISNULL slows down query

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a table that has either NULL or "Accepted" as values. My query returns about 250 rows.

If I add a where condition of -

```
AND Description = 'Accepted'
```

my 250 rows return in 2 seconds.

However, if I add a where condition of -

```
ISNULL(Description, '') = 'Accepted'
```

my 250 rows return in 47 seconds.

Has anyone encountered performance issues with using the ISNULL function? Unfortunately I am programatically limited to having to use ISNULL at this point.

Comment: Out of interest, how are you "programatically limited"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you include a field inside of a function, it changes how the optimizer has to run and forces it to ignore indexes.

see here: [What makes a SQL statement sargable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable)

Answer (score 8):

You can also bypass the functions entirely by using:

`WHERE (Description = 'Accepted' OR Description IS NULL)`

Answer (score 3):

Using

```
ISNULL(Description, '') = 'Accepted'
```

in your where condition doesnt make any sense in this case. If the description is null, the original where clause of

```
AND Description = 'Accepted'
```

will still suffice.
You are basically comparing '' with 'Accepted' in every row where the description is null.

Please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish with the query, i think you might be going in the wrong direction.

Comment: +1 pointing out the bleeding obvious: both evaluate to false/unknown when NULL which is effectively the same. I'd probably have overlooked this too.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to use this in the WHERE condition, use IS NULL, not ISNULL

> SELECT field FROM table WHERE description is null

or the opposite

> SELECT field FROM table WHERE NOT description is null